# issue with INSERT using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm running an AJAX call that passes some variables to a PHP script which is supposed to `INSERT` into a table.  For reasons that are unbeknownst to me, is it not.

**The AJAX call gets a success, so presumably to problems there.**

```
$('#rate_button').click(function(){
var varate = $('#u_varate').val(),
    fharate = $('#u_fharate').val(),
    usdarate = $('#u_usdarate').val(),
    conv15rate = $('#u_conv15rate').val(),
    conv5rate = $('#u_conv5rate').val(),
    conv20rate = $('#u_conv20rate').val();

$('#varate').val(varate);
$('#fharate').val(fharate);
$('#usdarate').val(usdarate);
$('#conv15rate').val(conv15rate);
$('#conv5rate').val(conv5rate);
$('#conv20rate').val(conv20rate);
var rates = $('#rates').serialize();
    rurl = 'http://www.nexthometown.com/components/com_singleprop/views/singleprop/tmpl/scripts/rates.php?' + rates;

$.ajax({
    url: rurl,
    success: function(){
       $('#success').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500); 
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Oopsy!');
    }
});
});
```

**The PHP script called by the AJAX function.  I don't get an `error` callback from AJAX, so I guess this runs ok?**

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');


$varate = $_GET['varate'];
$fharate = $_GET['fharate'];
$usdarate = $_GET['usdarate'];
$conv15rate = $_GET['conv15rate'];
$conv5rate = $_GET['conv5rate'];
$conv20rate =  $_GET['conv20rate'];

$query = "INSERT INTO singleprop.jos_rates(varate, fharate, usdarate, convfifteen, convfive, convtwenty)VALUES('" . $varate . "', '" . $fharate . "', '" . $usdarate ."', '" . $conv15rate . "', '" . $conv20rate . "');";

$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Also, when I run the script itself in the browser and had it `echo` the valiables, Everything ran fine.

When I copy the `INSERT` argument and but it in a CMD with proper values, it works fine.

Comment: $conv5rate = $_GET['conv5rate']; Did you insert this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your sql has 6 fields but only 5 values given. You are missing `$conv5rate`.

Comment: dude, you need to escape your values because your code is wide open for sql injection.

Comment: How do you escape values?  I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: in your case you using deprecated mysql_* functions which you should change. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for info on how to escape your values. Then take a look at the warning on the top of that page.

Comment: I know it's deprecated, but when I try to use `mysqli` in its place, things stop working.

Comment: So I used `substr` after `$_GET` for each one to cut the number to characters down to 7 characters.  Should that be enough to make it safe?

Comment: no use mysql_real_escape_string. example: $varate = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['varate']);

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem to me:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO singleprop.jos_rates(varate, fharate, usdarate, convfifteen, convfive, convtwenty)VALUES('" . $varate . "', '" . $fharate . "', '" . $usdarate ."', '" . $conv15rate . "', '" . $conv20rate . "');";
```

You are specifying 6 columns but only giving it 5 values. I believe that is a SQL syntax error for insert. It looks like you're missing the $conv5rate entry.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `data` property of settings object that you pass to your ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you use it, you can make your JS code much simpler:

```
$('#rate_button').click(function(){
 var data = {varate:$('#u_varate').val(),
            fharate:$('#u_fharate').val(),
            usdarate:$('#u_usdarate').val(),
            conv15rate:$('#u_conv15rate').val(),
            conv5rate:$('#u_conv5rate').val(),
            conv20rate:$('#u_conv20rate').val()
           };

    rurl = 'http://www.nexthometown.com/components/com_singleprop/views/singleprop/tmpl/scripts/rates.php';

$.ajax({
    url: rurl,
    type:'GET',
    data:data,
    success: function(){
       $('#success').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500); 
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Oopsy!');
    }
});
});
```

Also, when you make an sql query, you should sanitize variables you pass to it. Otherwise your code is opened for sql injections.
You can do, at least, like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO singleprop.jos_rates(varate, fharate, usdarate, convfifteen, convfive, convtwenty)VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($varate) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($fharate) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($usdarate) ."', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($conv15rate) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($conv5rate) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($conv20rate) . "');";
```

Here is more info about that function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Also, just for future, it is recommended to use PDO because mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed.

Comment: I've also looked at doing `.serialize` for my data values, but I like to see them all in one place so I know what's getting pulled in, plus I can omit things when needed.  Plus I actually update hidden values instead of passing values straight to the server because I use those values elsewhere.  But thanks for the tip!

Comment: You do not understand. You collect your variables into hidden fields and than serialize a form with those fields. Than add received string to an url. Useless work. Code in my answer adds variables to be passed on the server in temporary JS object. Which is much easier to work with comparing to hidden fields. And faster. And this line in ajax call: `data:data,` will tell jquery - take that object, serialize it, and pass to server. On your server side nothing will change. But you will not need numerous hidden fields. And code looks cleaner.

Comment: I get it, I just use those hidden fields for other things to display the data that was altered.

Comment: Uh. Sorry, it was not clear to me. Just pointed on a thing that seemed strange to me.

Comment: I get it.  No Worries.  Believe me, if I were presented with a better way to do something, I wouldn't hesitate.  I get all kinds of great info from this site, most of the time without even having to post a question.